# XamlReader.Load with ParseException in WinUI

Tags: winui

I try to parse a simple xaml string in WinUI but I have problems to use my converters. I cannot import the converters namespace.

```cs
var dataTemplate = XamlReader.Load(
    @"
<DataTemplate
    xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
    xmlns:converters=""using:Sample.Converters"">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment=""Left"">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <converters:DoubleToGridLengthConverter x:Key=""DoubleToGridLengthConverter"" />  
        </Grid.Resources>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>");
```

Comment: I find a solution. I define the converter as an application resource and now all works fine!